# Prevent Popen from changing python version

Tags: python, subprocess, version

when I run the below code:

```
output = subprocess.Popen("python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])'", shell=True)
print(output.communicate()[0])
```

I get (3, 4, 3, 'final', 0) 
as the output indicating that it ran python3.4

however when I run `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])'` in the terminal I get (2, 7, 6, 'final', 0) indicating that it ran python2. I am not sure how to have popen run python2.

I also found that when I call popen to run a shell script that runs a python script it will default to python3 even when the script has `#!/usr/bin/env python` which points to python2.

Comment: Can you just call `python2.7 ...`? For the record, your example runs 2.7 from a 3.6 environment for me (I have 2.7 as the default bound to `python` though).

Comment: What Operating System/Distro are we talking?

Comment: Do you have an alias for `python`? The shell used by `Popen` won't expand aliases.

Comment: What does `type python` say?

Comment: @digitalarbeiter Seems like it must be Unix/Linux, since he runs scripts that begin with `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @digitalarbeiter Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: @Barmar python is /usr/bin/python both with Popen and through terminal

Comment: @CJ59 although I would perfer if Popen would run the python2.7 as default calling python2.7 solved my immediate problem. Thank you.